# UIButton Text Abbreviating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Alright, This is so simple that it bugs me so much. I am trying to change the text of a button from "Text" to "Text (1)". So easy right? The text in the IB is set as "Text" and I am telling it through an action to change the text to the following string:

```
- (IBAction)textChange {

  button.titleLabel.text = @"Text (1)";

}
```

However something idiotic is happening. When it changes the text the button text is being abbreviated like so "Te...)". Why would it be doing this if I can type in the value "Text (1)" in the button in IB and it fits and shows the text like it should? The width of the button is 207 and the font size is set to 15..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your text in:

```
[button setTitle:@"Text (1)" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and in:

```
[button setTitle:@"Text (1)" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: How will this fix the problem?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw it actually did. Because I guess the fact that I wasnt listing the states when setting the title?

Comment: @Zack I have no clue, I can't believe something as simple as this fixed a formatting issue haha... +1

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you are in the design tool of XCode the text feeds but when you build and run, the abbreviations appears. It happened to me before. Try to enlarge the button and try again.

Comment: Ive already enlarged it to the full width of the screen. Also what I just found out is that the text reverts back to "Text" when the button is pressed...